# Angular Universal API CALL, giving data as null for few properties

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-universal

I have an angular universal app, which calls and API. everything works fine when javascript is enabled. but as soon as I disable the javascript to test the server-side rendering, I can see, what URL and API is getting called in my logs,

I can see the response as null for few parameters, and black [] for rest. but API gives a proper response, I am using angular version 5.2

for eg:

```
{ 
      MaximumDays: null,
      MaximumDaysApplied: '',
      MinimumDays: null,
      MinimumDaysApplied: '',
      ProductCategories: null,
      ProductCategoryApplied: '',
      ProductItems: [],
      ProductSubCategories: null,
      ProductSubCategoryApplied: '',
      StartingLocations: null,
      TotalRows: 0 
}
```